# Constant python/django errors

Tags: python, django

Does anyone know what I should do? I receive this error everytime I interact with my localhost.

It does not crash, my terminal just blows up with these exceptions. Does anyone know how I should proceed with this issue?

I know this is alot of errors but I am starting to learn more about Django so your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50979)
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50974)
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50978)
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50980)
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50981)
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/Emmanuel/.local/share/virtualenvs/thepillow-kX0pGe6_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/Emmanuel/.local/share/virtualenvs/thepillow-kX0pGe6_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/Emmanuel/.local/share/virtualenvs/thepillow-kX0pGe6_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/Emmanuel/.local/share/virtualenvs/thepillow-kX0pGe6_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/Emmanuel/.local/share/virtualenvs/thepillow-kX0pGe6_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/Emmanuel/.local/share/virtualenvs/thepillow-kX0pGe6_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/Emmanuel/.local/share/virtualenvs/thepillow-kX0pGe6_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/Emmanuel/.local/share/virtualenvs/thepillow-kX0pGe6_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/Emmanuel/.local/share/virtualenvs/thepillow-kX0pGe6_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/Emmanuel/.local/share/virtualenvs/thepillow-kX0pGe6_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Not Found: /favicon.ico
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50982)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/Emmanuel/.local/share/virtualenvs/thepillow-kX0pGe6_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/Emmanuel/.local/share/virtualenvs/thepillow-kX0pGe6_/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
'''
```

Comment: first of all can you add please the tree of your project

Comment: I am having problem using tree on mac book pro. Please see the below if it helps:

/users/emmanuel/desktop/APPFOLDER
/users/emmanuel/desktop/APPFOLDER/APPNAME
/users/emmanuel/desktop/APPFOLDER/APPNAME/migrations
/users/emmanuel/desktop/APPFOLDER/APPNAME/templates
/users/emmanuel/desktop/APPFOLDER/APPNAME/templates/APPNAME
/users/emmanuel/desktop/APPFOLDER/media
/users/emmanuel/desktop/APPFOLDER/media/profile_pics

Comment: add the <head> tag of your html page, apparently the problem is with the Not Found: /favicon.ico

Comment: Thanks! What about all the ConnectionResetErrors?

: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Comment: I will post the answer along with the explanation for future references, and you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is raised by the fav.ico because django server is always resetting after not finding a favicon so If you add one. Even though If you never explicitly load one, django try and load a default one from the root of the project. you can use [favicon io](https://favicon.io/favicon-generator/) to make a simple fav icon. you put it inside your static folder and load it like that :

```
{% load static %}
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'images/favicon.ico' %}" />
```